# Count Unique Selection from Multiple Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, counting

I'm new to jquery, I'm working on a survey form and I have multiple dropdown menus for different questions but they all have the same dropdown value. Supposed I have:

```
<select name="Forms[AgentIsPitch]" id="Forms_AgentIsPitch">
 <option value="">Choose One</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
</select>   


<select name="Forms[MandatoryOptIsStated]" id="Forms_MandatoryOptIsStated">
 <option value="">Choose One</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
</select>
```

And other different dropdowns with different id's. What is the best way to count  how many has selected Yes, No and N/A/ ? Thanks

Comment: can you make a fiddle with your full code?

Comment: There you go https://jsfiddle.net/h8sLxw6y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it simple this way

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // get all selects
    var allSelects = $('select');

    // set values count by type
    var yes = 0;
    var no = 0;

    // for each select increase count
    $.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
        // increase count
        if($(s).val() == 'Yes') { yes++; }
        if($(s).val() == 'No') { no++; }
    });

    // update count values summary
    $('.cnt-yes').text(yes);
    $('.cnt-no').text(no);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nztwf4sc/)

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Acutally all of your answers works fine but this is the one I need coz I'll be needing to update some fields with current count of yes, no and n/a. So on select event works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In common you can use `change` event:

```
var results = {};

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  results[val] = (results[val] || 0) + 1;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uht6r3bu/)**

If you want count for each type of select:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if (!results[name]) {
        results[name] = {};
    }
  results[name][val] = (results[name][val] || 0) + 1;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uht6r3bu/1/)

In the `results` will be something like this:

```
{
  "Forms[AgentIsPitch]": {
      "Yes": 1,
      "No": 2,
      "N/A": 3
  },
  "Forms[MandatoryOptIsStated]": {
      "No": 5,
      "N/A": 13
  },  
}
```

**UPD:** for counting current choice:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var results = {};

    $('select').each(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            results[val] = (results[val] || 0) + 1;
        }
    })

    console.log(results);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uht6r3bu/2/)

Comment: It works but what I want to do is NOT to count how many Yes, No and N/A has been selected on each dropdown, I want to count how many Yes, No and N/A has been selected in all dropdown list, so if we have 2 dropdownlist that selected both Yes, the count for Yes should be two, however if dropdown list has selected again for example, No, then the count should be 1 Yes and 1 No.

Answer (score 0):

Try this — https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/h8sLxw6y/2/:

```
var count = {};
count.empty = $('select option:selected[value=""]').length;
count.yes = $('select option:selected[value="Yes"]').length;
count.no = $('select option:selected[value="No"]').length;
count.nA = $('select option:selected[value="N/A"]').length;

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

## My way to do it would be :

```
    var optionsYes = $("option[value$='Yes']:selected");
    var optionsNo = $("option[value$='No']:selected");
    var optionsNA = $("option[value$='N/A']:selected");

    console.log('number of yes selected = ' + optionsYes .length);
    console.log('number of no selected = ' + optionsNo .length);
    console.log('number of N/A selected = ' + optionsNA .length);
```

*Check the console (or replace with alert).*

**With your code, it would be something like that (*assuming you want to check on a button click event*) :**

```
<select name="Forms[AgentIsPitch]" id="Forms_AgentIsPitch">
 <option value="">Choose One</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
</select>   


<select name="Forms[MandatoryOptIsStated]" id="Forms_MandatoryOptIsStated">
 <option value="">Choose One</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
</select>  

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="countYes"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#countYes').on('click', function(){
    var optionsYes = $("option[value$='Yes']:selected");
    var optionsNo = $("option[value$='No']:selected");
    var optionsNA = $("option[value$='N/A']:selected");

    console.log('number of yes selected = ' + optionsYes .length);
    console.log('number of no selected = ' + optionsNo .length);
    console.log('number of N/A selected = ' + optionsNA .length);
   });
</script>
```

*You can check at another event, I choosed a button click just for example.*

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a cleaner way to do this, but this will get the job done (assuming there is a button click to trigger things):

```
$("#theButton").on('click', function() {
    var totalSelect = 0;
    var totalYes = 0;
    var totalNo = 0;
    var totalNA = 0;

    $("select").each(function(){

        totalSelect++;

        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") { totalYes++; } 
        if ($(this).val() == "No") { totalNo++; } 
        if ($(this).val() == "N/A") { totalNA++; }

    });
});
```

Hope this helps the cause.